# ошибка при удалении VkDebugReportCallbackEXT

Tags: c#, vulkan

при вызове метода `vkDestroyDebugReportCallbackEXT` выдаёт ошибку

> vkDestroyDebugReportCallbackEXT: required parameter pAllocator->pfnReallocation specified as NULL. The spec valid usage text states 'pfnReallocation must be a valid pointer to a valid user-defined PFN_vkReallocationFunction

и

> System.AccessViolationException: Попытка чтения или записи в защищенную память.

метод объявил так
`void vkDestroyDebugReportCallbackEXT(IntPtr instance, IntPtr callback, IntPtr pAllocator);`

вызываю так

```
vkDestroyDebugReportCallbackEXT(instance.Hanble,callback.Hanble,IntPtr.Zero);
```

сам объект `VkDebugReportCallbackEXT` работает

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Вообщем для хранения `VkDebugReportCallbackEXT` нужно было использовать `UInt64` а не `IntPtr`